# Android-x86 in Vmware workstation fails to start

Tags: android-x86, vmware

I need to emulate an Android 4.2 device in Vmware Workstation 7.1.

I downloaded the image **android-x86-4.2-20130228.iso** from http://www.android-x86.org/download. I tried to run it as a live-cd and also installed it on the VM harddisk (much like described at http://www.walterdevos.be/installing-android-x86-4-0-in-vmware-player). In either case I got the following console screen:

[image]

taken from [this topic in the google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-x86/kW8YE6_eXXU). So, you may see the problem occurs not only in my environment. I tried recommended setting from the topic (`... nomodeset vga=(any unreal mode such  as 987877 or 5785 etc)`) as a possible workaround. Nothing helps.

The question: how to fix the problem and run android-x86 in Vmware Workstation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over time new versions of Android-x86 appear, and the problem is solved now by the next available release - [build 20130725](http://www.android-x86.org/releases/build-20130725) with Android 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

Last android iso did not work for me, I had to rely on [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225446/215181) procedure,
including a grub config file edition, and the choice of an iso recommended for vmware.