# Android on virtualbox can't move mouse pointer

Tags: android-x86, mouse, virtualbox

I installed [Android-x86 6.0-r3.iso](https://www.fosshub.com/Android-x86.html/android-x86-6.0-r3.iso) in VirtualBox Manager 5.1.22_Ubuntu (Ubuntu 17.04). Now if I want to touch anything via mouse pointer I have to move the pointer but I can't move the pointer without clicking left mouse button. But clicking left mouse button represents touch functionality. How can I move the pointer without touching (left click) "display"?

[image]

Comment: That's probably the "mouse integration" stuff: no "seemless mouse" without the vbox-guest-utilities installed – and AFAIK those are not available for Android. The first "click" inside the Android window should just "capture" the mouse (no other action), and you can "free" it again with "Right Ctrl" (see lower-right corner in your screenshot). // BTW: Could you give some details on how you installed Android in Virtual Box? What image and settings did you use? As you're on Ubuntu, those details [could help here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/170142/16575).

Comment: PS: Also take a look at the existing Debian answer. The step on mouse support might be interesting.

Comment: @Izzy, thx for the link change settings "Pointing Device to PS/2 Mouse" solves the problem.

Comment: Glad to read! Mind to [answer your own question](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) then? Though it's part of the one linked to, it's the part specific to your issue. You could elaborate a little more detailed on this aspect (steps taken etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was mentioned in the comments above, there is reference for Android X86 – mouse support in Oracle VirtualBox linked in [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/170142/how-to-run-android-in-virtualbox-on-linux) answer. AFAIK I had not to install additional packages like `vbox-guest-utillities`. As you can see the following list is empty:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep virtualbox-guest
$ dpkg -l | grep vbox-guest
```

I only had to change the "Pointing Device" under Settings > System > Motherboard to "PS/2 Mouse".

[image]